# Can't fix syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

The script works however in Dreamweaver, I keep getting a syntax error. I'm not sure how to fix this and still make the script work.

http://jsfiddle.net/tBptU/

According to DW the syntax error is on line 21 after `return false;`

Comment: For all I see the code is fine. By the way, why dreamweaver?

Comment: rambo , run the code in firefox and see if you get any error in firebug , code looks fine, you closed every..thing properly

Comment: Please do not use third party tools. You can post your code here (see [help on formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).

Comment: @thisMayhem, why not Dreamweaver?

Comment: @Gumbo I used Jsfiffle for the purpose of testing the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it. Note that with jSFiddle you don't include the script tag in the JavaScript frame. (see the JSLint Errors). Remove the tag and it works.

Comment: in the actual code we need the script tags right , he is running in dreamweaver.

Comment: @gov of course you have to wrap JavaScript in script tags in your page source. No idea why DW would report an error.. the script is fine.